# How can I decouple system design from unit tests (as suggested by Uncle Bob)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, tdd

Uncle Bob (Bob Martin) mentioned in his [blog](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html) that in order to decouple our system's design from unit tests, we should not expose our concrete classes directly to the unit tests. Rather, we should just expose an API that represents our system, and then use this API for unit testing.

[A rough representation of Uncle Bob's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGkzl.png)

According to my understanding, I think that by an API, he meant an *interface*. So the unit tests should be interacting with interfaces instead of real classes.

My question is this: If we are exposing only interfaces to our unit tests, how do these unit tests get access to the actual implementations to verify their behavior? Should we use DI in our tests to inject the real classes at run time? Is there any way for the code below to work?

ILoanEligibility.cs

```
public interface ILoanEligibility
{
    bool HasCorrectType(string loanType);
}
```

LoanEligibility.cs

```
public class LoanEligibility : ILoanEligibility
{
    public bool HasCorrectType(string loanType)
    {
        if(loanType.Equals("Personal"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
[TestClass]
public class LoanEligibilityTest
{
    ILoanEligibility _loanEligibility;
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLoanTypePersonal()
    {
        //Arrange
        string loanType = "Personal";

        //Act
        bool expected = _loanEligibility.HasCorrectType(loanType);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(expected);
    }
}
```

The above unit test tries to see if LoanEligibility.HasCorrectType() method works properly for "Personal" type. Obviously, the test will fail as we are not using a concrete class, but rather an interface, in accordance with Uncle Bob's suggestion (if I understood it correctly).

How do I make this test pass? Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Edit 1**
Thank you @bleepzter for suggesting Moq. Following is the modified unit test class, testing both valid and invalid cases.

```
[TestClass]
public class LoanEligibilityTest
{
    private Mock<ILoanEligibility> _loanEligibility;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLoanTypePersonal()
    {
        SetMockLoanEligibility();
        //Arrange
        string loanType = "Personal";
        //Act
        bool expected = _loanEligibility.Object.HasCorrectType(loanType);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLoanTypeInvalid()
    {
        SetMockLoanEligibility();
        //Arrange
        string loanType = "House";
        //Act
        bool expected = _loanEligibility.Object.HasCorrectType(loanType);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(expected);
    }

    public void SetMockLoanEligibility()
    {
        _loanEligibility = new Mock<ILoanEligibility>();
        _loanEligibility.Setup(loanElg => loanElg.HasCorrectType("Personal"))
                        .Returns(true);
    }
}
```

But now I am confused. Since we are not *really* testing our concrete class but rather its mock, are these unit tests really telling us anything, other than probably that our mocks are working fine?

Comment: You have misunderstood what was meant by that statement

Comment: @Nkosi, Thank you, I thought so, too. Could you please point me somewhere that explains this in detail with the help of a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - you would use mocking framework such as Moq.

The overall idea is that Interfaces or abstract classes provide "contracts" or a set of standardized API's which you can code against.

The implementation of these interfaces or abstract classes can be unit tested individually. This is not a problem, and in fact - that is what you should do on a regular basis.

However, the complexity arises when those implementations are dependencies of other objects. In that regard - to unit test such a complex object, you first have to construct the implementation of the dependency, plug that dependency into the instance of whatever you are testing.

This process becomes quite burdensome because as the dependency chain grows - the variability of how the code behaves can be quite complex. To simplify the tests and also to be able to unit tests multiple conditions in complex dependency chains - we use mocking frameworks.

What the mock provides is a way to "fake" an implementation with specific parameters (input/output, whatever they may be) and plug those fakes into the dependency graph. And while yes - you can mock concrete objects - it is a lot easier to mock contracts defined by an interface or an abstract class.

A decent starting point to understand those concepts is the moq framework documentation. https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Edit:

I see there is a confusion about what this means so I wanted to elaborate.

Common design patterns (known as S.O.L.I.D) dictate that an object should do 1 thing, and 1 thing only and do it well. This is known as the Single Responsibility Principle.

Another core concept is that an object should depend upon abstractions and not concrete implementations. This concept is known as the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Finally - the Liskov Substitution Principle, dictates that object in a program should be replaceable with instances of their sub-types without altering the correctness of the program. In other words - if your objects depend on abstractions, then you can provide different implementations (taking advantage of inheritance) for those abstractions without fundamentally altering the behavior of the application.

Which also neatly jumps into the Open/Closed principle. IE - software entities should be open for extension, but closed for modification. (Think of providing different implementations for those abstractions).

Finally - we have the Inversion of Control principle - a complex object should not be responsible for creating its own dependencies; something else should be responsible for creating them, and they should be "injected" via constructor, method, or property injection wherever they are needed.

**So how does this apply in "decoupling system design" from unit tests?**

The answer is very simple.

Suppose we are writing a software that models cars. 
A car has a body and wheels, and all sorts of other internal components. 
For simplicity we will say that an object of type `Car` has a constructor that takes four `wheel` objects as parameters:

```
public class Wheel {
   public double Radius { get; set; }
   public double RPM { get; set; }
   public void Spin(){ ... }
   public double GetLinearVelocity() { ... }
}

public class LinearMovement{
   public double Velocity { get; set; }     
}

public class Car {

  private Wheel wheelOne;
  private Wheel wheelTwo;
  private Wheel wheelThree;
  private Wheel wheelFour;

  public Car(Wheel one, Wheel two, Wheel three, Wheel four){
    wheelOne = one;
    wheelTwo = two;
    wheelThree = three;
    wheelFour = four;
  } 

  public LinearMovement Move(){
    wheelOne.Spin();
    wheelTwo.Spin();
    wheelThree.Spin();
    wheelFour.Spin();

    speedOne = wheelOne.GetLinearVelocity();
    speedTwo = wheelTwo.GetLinearVelocity();
    speedThree = wheelThree.GetLinearVelocity();
    speedFour = wheelFour.GetLinearVelocity();

    return new LinearMovement(){ 
       Velocity = (speedOne + speedTwo + speedThree + speedFour) / 4
    };
  }
}
```

The ability of a car to move is governed the kind of wheels the car has. A wheel can have a soft rubber thereby gluing the car to the road around corners, or it can be very narrow for deep snow but very slow speeds.

Therefore - the idea of a wheel becomes an abstraction. There is all sorts of wheels out there, and a concrete implementation of a wheel cannot possibly cover all of them. Enter the dependency inversion principle.

We make wheel an abstraction using `IWheel` interface to declare the basic minimum functionality for what any wheel should be capable of doing in order to work with our car. (In our case it should spin at least...)

```
public interface IWheel {
    double Radius { get; set; }
    double RPM { get; set; }
    void Spin();
    double GetLinearVelocity();
}

public class BasicWheel : IWheel {
   public double Radius { get; set; }
   public double RPM { get; set; }
   public void Spin(){ ... }
   public double GetLinearVelocity() { ... }   
}

public class Car {
    ...
    public Car(IWheel one, IWheel two, IWheel three, IWheel four){
    ...
    } 

    public LinearMovement Move(){
        wheelOne.Spin();
        wheelTwo.Spin();
        wheelThree.Spin();
        wheelFour.Spin();

        speedOne = wheelOne.GetLinearVelocity();
        speedTwo = wheelTwo.GetLinearVelocity();
        speedThree = wheelThree.GetLinearVelocity();
        speedFour = wheelFour.GetLinearVelocity();

        return new LinearMovement(){ 
            Velocity = (speedOne + speedTwo + speedThree + speedFour) / 4
        };
    }
}
```

So that's great, we got an abstraction to define a basic functionality of a wheel and we coded the car against that abstraction. Nothing changed in the code of how the car moves - thereby satisfying the Liskov Substitution Principle.

So now if instead of creating a car with basic wheels, and we create a car with RacingPerformanceWheels the code that governs how the car moves stays the same. This satisfies the Open / Closed principle.

However - it poses another problem. The actual velocity of the car - is dependent on the average linear velocity of all 4 wheels. So depending on the wheel - the car will behave differently.

**How do we test the behavior of the car given that there could be a million different types of wheels out there?!?**

Enter the mocking framework. Because the movement of the car depends on the abstract notion of a wheel defined by the interface `IWheel` - we can now mock different implementations of such wheel, each with predefined parameters.

***The concrete wheel implementations/objects themselves (`BasicWheel`, `RacingPerformanceWheel`, etc..) should be unit tested without mocks.*** The reason is that they do not have dependencies of their own. If the wheel had a dependency in it's constructor - than mocking should be used for that dependency.

***To test the car object - mocks should be used to describe each `IWheel` instance (dependency) that is passed to the constructor of the car.*** This provides a couple of advantages - decoupling the overall system design from unit tests:

1) We don't care what wheels there are in the system. There could be 1 million of them.

2) We care that for specific wheel dimensions, at given angular velocity (RPM) - the car should achieve a very specific linear velocity.

The mock of `IWheel` for the requirements of #2 would tell us if our vehicle is working properly, and if not - we could change our code to correct the mistake.

Comment: Thank you @bleepzter. I have edited my question to add the Moq-based code. Could you please have a look at it and let me know if that is what you suggested?

Comment: After implementing Moq, I feel as if instead of testing the real concrete class, I am just testing the mocks. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Correct. You use mocks of the interfaces not to test the actual implementation, but to test complicated objects that use them. The implementation themselves you test normally with regular unit tests without mocking. So if something was using `ILoanEligibility` - instead of giving it an actual implemenation (aka an instance of the `LoanEligibility` class) you would give it a mock. The actual `LoanEligibility` class you would unit test as normal, as it does not have any other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

> Rather, we should just expose an API that represents our system, and
>   then use this API for unit testing.

Correct

> According to my understanding, I think that by an API, he meant an
>   interface. So the unit tests should be interacting with interfaces
>   instead of real classes.

Here you misunderstood first statement.
First in unit tests you need to test actual implementation to verify their behaviour.
Then in unit tests you will instantiate actual classes **but you allow to use only methods and types consumer of your API have access to**.

In your particular example

```
[TestClass]
public class LoanEligibilityTest
{        
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLoanTypePersonal()
    {
        //Arrange
        ILoanEligibility loanEligibility = new LoanEligibility(); // actual implementation
        string loanType = "Personal";

        //Act
        bool expected = _loanEligibility.HasCorrectType(loanType);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(expected);
    }
}
```

Suggestion: With Arrange-Act-Assert approach in "Act" section you allow to use only methods and types provided by API.

Comment: Thank you @Fabio for this insight ! :) However, say, tomorrow ILoanEligibility has a new implementation and we want to switch to this new class. Won't it create an overhead of making this change throughout our unit tests? I mean, yes, the same overhead will be present even if we use the real class instead of the interface. But we are not really "decoupled" from the class in the way it is really intended, are we? The tests still, kind of, depend on the actual class. I understand that this approach ensures that the tests interact with the API, but do you think we can somehow fix this problem?

Comment: @HemantSingh, tests **must** depend on the actual implementation, because you testing behaviour of this implementation. When you want change behaviour by introducing new class - you will write new tests for the this implementation. Consider tests as entry point of application, where you testing actual implementation. Abstract/mock only things which makes tests slow or very very complex to configure(Arrange section).

Comment: Agreed @Fabio. I was just wondering if there is a way to abstract away real classes and let the tests talk to the API/interface instead. Much like Dependency injection. Won't it reduce our work load when say, we have to replace LoanEligiblity class with NewLoanEligibility only at a single place of interface-to-class mapping, instead of in each test that uses that class. Is it such a bad idea to inject classes in our tests instead of including them directly?

Comment: If you want replace with the class which have similar behaviour(because you expect to pass against same tests), then you can always introduce factory method or class which will be the "only" place where you can change actual class.

Answer (score -1):

> If we are exposing only interfaces to our unit tests, how do these unit tests get access to the actual implementations to verify their behavior?

Any way you like.

One approach I've found satisfactory is to write the checks in an abstract class, and pass in an instance of the system under test from the constructor of an otherwise empty class that extends the abstract class.

In a lot of ways, test frameworks are ... well... "frameworks" (obviously)... and therefore it can make sense to think about your testable components as something to be injected into the framework.  See Mark Seemann for an exploration of what a [DI friendly framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) might look like, and decide if you think those ideas are reasonable for your test suites.

You *can* do test first in this style, but I'm going to admit that some of the moves that separate the concerns are going to feel a little bit contrived -- introducing interfaces early, because you really understand what API is going to be comfortable to use, is perhaps dubious.

(One answer might be to take time out to spike the interface, before getting invested in writing checks for the implementation.)